# How to log raw JSON to Cloudwatch from AWS Lambda in node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, console.log

I have some node.js based Lambdas that are logging data.

In order to properly query and filter the data etc, I want to log as pure JSON data from my Lambdas.

However, when I do a regular `console.log` it makes an ordinary string of the data.

```js
console.log({a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"})
```

Results in this:

```
2020-04-29T14:46:45.722Z    3f64c499-fbae-4a84-996c-5e5f0cb5302c    INFO    { a: 1, b: 2, x: 'xxx' }
```

The logged line above does not seem to be searchable as JSON using the various filter matching options in CloudWatch.

I've tried to call the `AWS.CloudWatchLogs` API directly but since I'm using lambda I cannot maintain a token between invocations of the functions, so I'm not sure that's the way to go.

Have anyone else had success in logging raw JSON from a Javascript Lambda?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `console.log()` does not go directly to stdout/stderr. You can see that using this Lambda:

```
const process = require('process');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("message 1");
    process.stdout.write("message 2\n");
};
```

If you invoke that, you will see output like this:

```
START RequestId: 6942bebc-1997-42cd-90c2-d76b44c637283 Version: $LATEST
2020-04-29T17:06:07.303Z    6935bebc-1d97-42cd-90c2-d76b4a637683    INFO    message 1
message 2
END RequestId: 6942bebc-1997-42cd-90c2-d76b44c637283
```

So to get the output you want you could either redefine `console.log` to go to stderr, or write to stdout/stderr directly.

Or you could use a logging framework that writes to stdout/stderr, which may give you more flexibility on how your messages are written. I don't do Node development, but I've heard that [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) is the standard logging framework.

Comment: Thanks, it works very well to write directly to stdout instead :)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the correct delimiter before the JSON data.

In your example, there is no delimiter before JSON data:

```js
console.log({a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"})
// {a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"}
```

The official documentation [AWS Lambda function logging in Node. js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html) is adding a newline `\n` character before the data. An example for your code snippet:

```js
console.log('\n%j', {a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"})
// \n{a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"}
```

That does not work either as of July 2022.

**The solution is to use the tab character `\t` as the delimiter between the message and the data.**

```js
console.log('\t%j', {a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"})
// \t{a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"}
```

An example of building a formatted message and adding structured data:

```js
const name = 'world';
console.log('hello %s\t%j', name, {a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"})
// hello world\t{a:1,b:2,x:"xxx"}
```